# How to access document on alfresco?

Tags: alfresco, opencmis

I created a project alfresco amp.
To add a document, I run this Test class:

```html
public class Test {

   public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
      Map<String, String> sessionParameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
      sessionParameters.put(SessionParameter.USER, "admin");
      sessionParameters.put(SessionParameter.PASSWORD, "admin");
      sessionParameters.put(SessionParameter.ATOMPUB_URL, "http://localhost:8080/alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.1/atom");
      sessionParameters.put(SessionParameter.BINDING_TYPE, BindingType.ATOMPUB.value());
      SessionFactory sessionFactory = SessionFactoryImpl.newInstance();
      Session lSession = sessionFactory.getRepositories(sessionParameters).get(0).createSession();
      Folder root = lSession.getRootFolder();
                Map<String, Object> folderProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                folderProperties.put(PropertyIds.OBJECT_TYPE_ID, "cmis:folder");
                folderProperties.put(PropertyIds.NAME, "oo");
                Folder newFolder = root.createFolder(folderProperties);
      Map<String, Object> lProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
      String name = "lol.txt";
      lProperties.put(PropertyIds.OBJECT_TYPE_ID, "cmis:document");
      lProperties.put(PropertyIds.NAME, name);
      byte[] content = "CMIS Testdata One".getBytes();
                InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(content);
                ContentStream contentStream = new ContentStreamImpl(name, new BigInteger(content), "text/plain", stream);
                Document newContent1 =  newFolder.createDocument(lProperties, contentStream, null);
      System.out.println("Document created: " + newContent1.getId());
   }
}
```

The document is created with success; I got: `Document created: e3184105-e59e-4b8a-88e7-9442942433a4;1.0`

My problem is how can I access to this document (With which url can I access to that document).
Please help?.

Comment: Access it how? Through Share? Through CMIS? Download? Other?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've created a document and you now want to know what URL to use to get to it. You have many options, some of which include...

1. Use the Alfresco web app's download URL:

   http://localhost:8080/alfresco/s/api/node/workspace/SpacesStore/dac36aab-dd49-4abc-a4bc-0e0d5729c9ad/content;cm%3Acontent
2. Use the Share web app's download URL:

   http://localhost:8080/share/proxy/alfresco/slingshot/node/content/workspace/SpacesStore/dac36aab-dd49-4abc-a4bc-0e0d5729c9ad/test.txt
3. Use the CMIS URL (AtomPub binding):

   http://localhost:8080/alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.1/atom/content/test.txt?id=dac36aab-dd49-4abc-a4bc-0e0d5729c9ad%3B1.0
4. Use the CMIS URL (Browser binding):

   http://localhost:8080/alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.1/browser/root?objectId=dac36aab-dd49-4abc-a4bc-0e0d5729c9ad%3B1.0&cmisselector=content
5. Write your own URL handler that fetches the input stream via CMIS and returns that stream to the requester. Assuming you are using something like Spring MVC, the code for that might look like:

   ```
   public InputStream download(String objectId) {
       Session session = getSession();
       CmisObject obj = session.getObject(objectId);
       Document doc = null;
       if (obj.getBaseTypeId().equals(BaseTypeId.CMIS_DOCUMENT)) {
           doc = (Document) obj;
       }
       return doc.getContentStream().getStream();
   }
   ```

Each of the above options assumes a test file in a test folder named "test.txt" with an Alfresco Node Reference of:

workspace://SpacesStore/dac36aab-dd49-4abc-a4bc-0e0d5729c9ad

And a CMIS Object ID of:

dac36aab-dd49-4abc-a4bc-0e0d5729c9ad;1.0